# Managed servers not using net.sf.ehcache.Cache (net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap instead)

Tags: memory, weblogic, ehcache

We have the same code on 4 managed servers , the memory dump shows 0 bytes on 2 of them for net.sf.ehcache.Cache. I cannot figure out how that is possible , can it be a configuration of the Weblogic 10.3 itself ?

Class               7/14/2016 w2    7/19/2016 w2    7/22/2016 w1    7/26/2016 w1
SelectableConcurrentHashMap 457,612,800 239,927,952 643,103,008 749,172,144 
Cache                 215,424,168   214,954,104         0          0

SelectableConcurrentHashMap refers to net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap
Cache refers to net.sf.ehcache.Cache
w1 and w2 are the 2 managed servers . As you can see w1 does not use net.sf.ehcache.Cache, how is that possible ?

Comment: Can you add the used Ehcache configuration? And what you mean by 'not using'

Comment: Class Bytes
 h1 h2 w1 w2
net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap  155,150,864 156,874,104 
net.sf.ehcache.Cache 163,368,728   218,318,832